# Is there a way to get all subclasses of a class without having to import the modules the classes are in?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using `__subclasses__` only seems to work if the module where the subclasses are is imported somewhere. I want to be able to find all the subclasses of a certain class without importing them anywhere

```py
class A:
  pass

class B(A):
  pass

class C(A):
  pass
```

In this example I would want to grab classes B and C and put them into a list. And to reiterate I want to do this without needing to do this anywhere in the project: `from x.x.x import B`.

**Background**

I am trying to create a library that when a request is made it sends a string with the request. With that string I want to do `if subclass.name == string`, instantiate sublclass and do something. I need the list of subclasses so I can loop over them and check this condition.

Comment: Do you mean `B` and `C` are potentially in different python files which are not used anywhere and you want to know about their existence? That really is not possible without actually reading / importing those files. If the file the class is in isn't loaded by Python the class doesn't exist. Also how is this question related to Django? Please don't add tags that aren't directly related to your question.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Yes that's what I want. I thought that was the case. I was hoping there was some way of doing it... I guess not.